# I found a historical OP_HASH256 hashlock unspent output with 1 Bitcoin still in it, is it spendable?

Tags: script

The output:

| Block Height | TXID | Output Index | Satoshi Amount | Locking Script | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 211914 | AF32BB06F12F2AE5FDB7FACE7CD272BE67C923E86B7A66A76DED02D954C2F94D | 0 | 100000000 | aa20000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f87 | Unspent |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon inspecting the hash we can observe that it matches the hash of Bitcoin's genesis block: [`000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f`](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/block/0).

However, the hash is in the wrong byte order, so the genesis block header can't be used to unlock it, and whomever created it had permanently burned his 1 Bitcoin because the reversed-byte hash has some unknown preimage which will likely never be discovered, so no, it is not spendable.

There is another output, with the correct byte order:

| Block Height | TXID | Output Index | Satoshi Amount | Locking Script | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 211997 | A4BFA8AB6435AE5F25DAE9D89E4EB67DFA94283CA751F393C1DDC5A837BBC31B | 0 | 100000000 | aa206fe28c0ab6f1b372c1a6a246ae63f74f931e8365e15a089c68d619000000000087 | Spent |

which was successfully [spent](https://explorer.viawallet.com/btc/tx/a4bfa8ab6435ae5f25dae9d89e4eb67dfa94283ca751f393c1ddc5a837bbc31b) by using Bitcoin's genesis block header as input script:

```
4c500100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003ba3edfd7a7b12b27ac72c3e67768f617fc81bc3888a51323a9fb8aa4b1e5e4a29ab5f49ffff001d1dac2b7c
```